# Unnumbered linguistic examples with glosses

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, linguex

I want to have an unnumbered and unindented linguistic example with glossing and free translation. In other words, I want what `\exg.` produces in `linguex`, but without the numbering and the indentation; or what `\sn` produces in `gb4e`, but without the identation.

I wonder what would be the cleanest way to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) package provides an environment designed for exactly this purpose. Numbered examples are introduced by `\ex`, but if you use `\exdisplay` instead, there will be no number and no indent:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % to display margin lines
\usepackage{lipsum} % to display dummy text

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=, belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex, aboveglftskip=-0.5ex} % gloss formatting

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

    \exdisplay
    \begingl
    \gla Some sentence in your target language. //
    \glb \textsc{indef} sentence in 2\textsc{sg.poss} target language //
    \glft `Some sentence in your target language.' //
    \endgl
    \xe

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `\gll`, provided in `linguex`. It works just as `\exg.` but without producing a number.