# ExPex - hide the example number

Tags: linguistics, expex

I'm trying to prevent [ExPex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en) glosses from being numbered. I've tried defining the number format to simply be an invisible character, but that fails as it seems that the character `X` must be present in the format string. Is there another way to hide the number completely?

My attempt:

```
\ex[exnoformat=\hphantom]
\begingl
\gla Something here//
\glc The gloss//
\glft ‘Something here’//
\endgl
\xe
```

Comment: This is related, though not quite a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175870/42880.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that you can create an unnumbered example using `\begingl...\endgl` without a surrounding `\ex...\xe`. However, you will not get the extra vertical space around it that you would with a numbered example. You also can't pass any example-level style commands to it, and any global commands that you want to apply across all examples (using `\lingeveryex` or `\lingEveryex`) won't apply to it.

The `expex` package provides a command `\exdisplay` that can be used in place of `\ex` when you want an unnumbered example that acts like a normal example except it has no number or indent. This is what the documentation says about it on p. 71 (this is kind of buried in a section about plain TeX tables that most LaTeX users wouldn't bother to read):

> Like `\ex`, `\exdisplay` must be closed by `\xe`. `\exdisplay...\xe` is just like `\ex...\xe` except that an example number is not printed and the horizontal dimensions `\numoffset` and `\textoffset` are irrelevant. `aboveexskip` and `belowexskip` play the same role, paragraph indentation is cancelled, `\lingeveryex` and `\lingEveryex` are executed, and `\excnt` is advanced.
>
> `\noexno` is provided in case the user wants to use `\exdisplay` for something other than a numbered example. It cancels the automatic advancement of `\excnt`. You can say `\exdisplay\noexno` or `\exdisplay[...]\noexno` to cancel `\excnt` advancement.

Here is an illustration of how this works so you can see the difference between omitting `\ex...\xe` and using `\exdisplay...\xe`. You can decide which one fits your needs better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
    
Here's an example without a surrounding \verb|\ex...\xe| environment. Notice the lack of vertical space before and after:

\begingl % this works, but you are missing the vertical space you typically get with \ex
\gla Something here//
\glb The gloss//
\glft `Something here'//
\endgl

When you put a normal numbered example using \verb|\ex...\xe| after unnumbered ones that only have \verb|\begingl...\endgl|, the numbers start at the beginning because the \verb|\excnt| count has not been incremented:

\ex % this is (1) and not (2) because the \excnt count does not advance when you use \begingl / \endgl without a surrounding environment
\begingl
\gla Something here//
\glb The gloss//
\glft `Something here'//
\endgl
\xe

Here's an unnumbered example with \verb|\exdisplay...\xe|. Notice that the vertical space surrounding the example is maintained.

\exdisplay % includes the spacing above and below a normal \ex, but without the numbered label; it also advances the \excnt, unless you use \noexno
\begingl
\gla Something here//
\glc The gloss//
\glft `Something here'//
\endgl
\xe
    
When you put a normal numbered example using \verb|\ex...\xe| after unnumbered ones that with \verb|\exdisplay...\endgl|, the number may be higher than you expect because the \verb|\excnt| count is incremented by \verb|\exdisplay| unless you put \verb|\noexno| inside the example.

\ex % this is numbered (3) instead of (2) because \exdisplay advanced the \excnt; use \noexno if you want your unnumbered examples to not advance the \excnt count
\begingl
\gla Something here//
\glb The gloss//
\glft `Something here'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works much better than my solution, thank you!

Comment: What about supressing the exno (and not advancing the counter) *but* still getting labelled parts? (i mean: `\pex[exno=,exnoformat=X] \a \xe` does this, but is there a smarter way?)

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out - the `\ex` command is providing the number. It, along with the closing `\xe`, can simply be omitted and the gloss will be formatted correctly.