# How to make linguex not number an example?

Tags: linguex

I would like to have an example without a number in parentheses on the left. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post MWE of what u tried

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: I think that you should precise a lot your question including your tries and research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label can be set with an optional argument in brackets, see for example page 7 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/linguex/doc/linguex-doc.pdf) where `\a.[$\alpha$)]` and `\b.[$\beta$)]` are used to print the labels α) and β). You can also provide an empty argument `[]` to print an example without a label.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex. First example

\ex.[] Unnumbered example

\ex. Next example

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You can also use the `expex` package (see for example [Unnumbered linguistic examples with glosses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175870/unnumbered-linguistic-examples-with-glosses)) which defines the command `\exdisplay` for unnumbered examples. Unlike `\ex.[]` in the `\linguex` package, `\exdisplay` is not indented. The default line spacing is bigger.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}
\ex First example \xe
\exdisplay Unnumbered example \xe
\ex Next example \xe
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]